Obstructions to Fpqc Sheafification
Let $k$ be a field, and $\mathsf{C}$ the usual fpqc site over $k$.
The inspiration for my question comes from the following construction. It is shown by Waterhouse in [1] that there exists a presheaf $\mathscr{F}:\mathsf{C}^{\text{op}}\longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ which does not have a sheafification in the fpqc topology. Indeed, fix a cardinal $\lambda$, and let $\mathscr{F}(A)$ be the set of locally constant functions $f:\operatorname{Spec} A\to\lambda$ for which $f(\mathfrak{p})$ has cardinality bounded by the cardinality of $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$. Suppose $L/k$ is any extension. It follows that if $\mathscr{F}$ admits a sheafification $\mathscr{G}$, then $\mathscr{F}(L)$ injects into $\mathscr{G}(k)$, a problem because $\mathscr{F}(L)$ has the same cardinality of $L$, and $L$ is arbitrarily large.
In order to get around this part of the proof, one could impose size bounds on $\mathsf{C}^{\text{op}}$, only working with $k$-algebras of cardinality less than some fixed cardinal $\alpha$. In general, is this "injection issue" the only obstruction to sheafification in the fpqc topology?
One typical choice for $\alpha$ appears to be a strongly inaccessible cardinal. Is this choice to preserve size-closure under the usual categorical operations in $\mathsf{C}^{\text{op}}$, such as taking tensor products, or is there (as I'd imagine) a more general reason?
(I apologize if my question is naive; I have very little experience with set theory!)
References:
[1] “Basically Bounded Functors and Flat Sheaves.” Pacific Journal of Mathematics 57, no. 2 (1975): 597–610.

Yes, the size issue is the only difficulty.
Here is a summary of what's going on in Waterhouse's paper. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Grothendieck site, i.e., a category equipped with a Grothendieck topology. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a presheaf of sets on $\mathcal{C}$. You would like to know that you can sheafify $\mathcal{F}$. You can use the usual construction $\mathcal{F}^+$, like you find in Hartshorne or any other introductory reference on sheaf theory, the old elementary construction that you do once to make the presheaf separated and then you do it again to get a sheaf. No problem: for each object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, the classical formula tells you that $\mathcal{F}^+(X)$ is a colimit, taken over all covers of $X$, of equalizers of values of $\mathcal{F}$ on the opens in the cover. At a glance, this looks like it works just fine for any Grothendieck site $\mathcal{C}$, since you're just taking a colimit of equalizers in the category of sets, and of course the category of sets is complete and co-complete.
The trouble is that, depending on the Grothendieck site $\mathcal{C}$, the collection of covers of $X$ might not be a set. So the colimit you take, when forming $\mathcal{F}^+(X)$, might be a colimit over a proper class, and these do not always exist in the category of sets. This size issue doesn't arise in the Zariski, etale, or fppf topologies on affine schemes, but it does arise in the fpqc topology.
If you do know that the class of covers of each object of $\mathcal{C}$ is a set, then the usual construction of the sheafification $\mathcal{F} \mapsto \mathcal{F}^{++}$ works just fine, essentially with all the same proofs as you see in a first course in algebraic geometry. That's why my answer to your question is "yes", i.e., the size issue is the only difficulty.

As you wrote, you can fix a strongly inaccessible cardinal (i.e., Grothendieck universe) and work within that universe. The answer to your second question, "Is this choice to preserve size-closure under the usual categorical operations", is also "yes": working with a strongly inaccessible cardinal is what guarantees that, if you make reasonable constructions that should stay within sets (and not yield proper classes), e.g. taking small limits and colimits, then you don't leave the chosen Grothendieck universe.
To demonstrate the point, instead of letting $\kappa$ be a strongly inaccessible cardinal, suppose you decide to let $\kappa$ be the opposite kind of cardinal, a very small cardinal, e.g. the cardinal number 4. Now you're going to study sheaves of sets on the fppf site of affine scheme whose rings of functions have at most $\kappa$ elements, i.e., at most $4$ elements. That's pretty weird: that collection of affine schemes isn't even closed under fiber products. Good luck trying to do any sheaf theory there! Letting $\kappa$ instead be strongly inaccessible guarantees that the $\kappa$ size bound doesn't interfere with the usual constructions you make in sheaf theory.

Anyway, one more point: you mention that choosing a Grothendieck universe is the standard approach. Maybe that's true, but there's a more elegant approach already in Waterhouse's paper, and I think this more elegant approach is (in a roundabout way) today becoming quite standard. Let's fix a Grothendieck topology on the category $Aff$ of affine schemes, and for each cardinal $\kappa$, let's write $Aff_{\kappa}$ for the category of affine schemes whose rings of functions have $\leq \kappa$ elements. Waterhouse tells you to do this: if $\kappa,\lambda$ are cardinals satisfying $\kappa < \lambda$, then for every presheaf of sets $\mathcal{F}$ on $Aff_{\kappa}$, you can Kan-extend $\mathcal{F}$ to a presheaf on $Aff_{\lambda}$. You can also Kan-extend $\mathcal{F}$ to a presheaf on $Aff$ itself. Call a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Aff$ basically bounded if it is Kan-extended up from a presheaf on $Aff_{\kappa}$ for some cardinal $\kappa$. Here $\kappa$ doesn't need to be strongly inaccessible, no assumptions on $\kappa$ at all, and you don't fix any particular $\kappa$: the basically bounded presheaves are the presheaves which are Kan-extended up from the presheaves on $Aff_{\kappa}$ for any $\kappa$ at all.
The category of basically bounded presheaves on $Aff$ has generally good properties, and Waterhouse shows that sheafification works just fine on the basically bounded presheaves, i.e., the colimit that you write down in defining $\mathcal{F}^+$ reduces to a set-sized colimit.
Waterhouse's "basically bounded" approach is pretty generalizable. Many years ago, at some point in my thesis I needed to consider fpqc stackifications of some Artin prestacks, and writing out how this works using the "basically bounded" approach was straightforward.
I think the same kind of "basically bounded" idea is built in to the popular "condensed" and "pyknotic" formalisms, so in that sense I think Waterhouse's "basically bounded presheaves" approach to fpqc sheafification might be more popular than picking a Grothendieck universe now.

I don't think people should worry about these things too much (and the "basically bounded" approach seems reasonable to me) but I have wondered for a long time whether you could systematically get away with using strong limit cardinals of high cofinality (something like $\beth_{(2^{\aleph_0})^+}$) instead of strongly inaccessible cardinals. Do you know of any hypothetical issues with that approach? (The reason I ask is that this is sort of implicitly how we deal with size issues in model theory.)

@JamesEHanson The only answer I know is naive and pretty self-evident: if the cardinal number $\kappa$ isn't strongly inaccessible, and you declare every set of cardinality $< \kappa$ to be "small" (morally, set-like) and every set of cardinaltiy $\geq\kappa$ to be "large" (morally, class-like), then you worry that at some point you will take a limit or colimit of a small diagram of small objects and get something large. I guess having a high cofinality tells you that you're unlikely to consider such diagrams in normal mathematical practice, but you have to remember to be careful about it.

@user509184 Thank you for your detailed answer. I could easily be missing something, but is it quick to see that only considering $k$-algebras $A$ (or even objects of some Grothendieck site) of some bounded cardinality implies that the class of covers of each $A$ forms a set?

Whoops, I suppose I should correct: I'm referring to the class of covers of some fixed $A$.

@LiminalSpace Yes. Here is a very elementary argument: fix a set $S$ of cardinality $\kappa$, and consider all the possible addition and multiplication tables which define a commutative $k$-algebra structure on the set $S$. There's at most $\kappa^{(\kappa^2)}$ such addition tables and $\kappa^{(\kappa^2)}$ such multiplication tables. So there's only a set of iso. classes of commutative $k$-algebras with $\kappa$ elements. So the whole category $Aff_{\kappa}$ is (skeletally) small. So there's only a set of covers, in $Aff_{\kappa}$, of any one of its objects.

@JamesEHanson I do not think the problem has been studied in detail, because it would mean having to pay attention to when one is using the axiom of replacement or its relatives.
